# How to JOIN a table in MySQL with a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, mysql, database, oracle

Now, I'm pretty sure that it's not possible, but I want to 1) Confirm this, and 2) Hear alternatives.

My solution today was to run the MySQL query, then use its result to construct a "NOT IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')" string, which I tacked onto the Oracle query before running it. Rather cumbersome, but it worked, and it's fast enough so far.

What is the typical way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical way, assuming the Oracle & MySQL databases are allowed to talk to one another, would be to create a database link on the Oracle instance, connecting to the MySQL one: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_how_create_database_link.htm

Then you can run queries in Oracle as though you're only ever working on a single database...